# HTTP Status 404 error

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I m trying to display my result using jsp instead of HTML.  I get a resource not found ( can't locate the jsp file ).
Here is the code in my java file...

```
//Forward to JSP
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WebContent/result.jsp");

// I also tried
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WebContent/result.jsp");
```

and I placed the result.jsp in the WebContent folder.

I got the following error

```
HTTP Status 404
message /SimpleJSPApp/WebContent/result.jsp
description The requested resource is not available.
```

My servers properties is set correctly.  It works for my other Servlet app.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
J.

Comment: try just `result.jsp` and actually forward to it

Answer (score 1):

You Don't have to mention `/WebContent/result.jsp` only mention jsp name `result.jsp`

After this

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
```

Just forward the request using

```
rd.forward(request,response);
```

You can also `include` the result , here is a nice [article](http://www.javatpoint.com/requestdispatcher-in-servlet) about Request Dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code to use

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher =request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
dispatcher.foward(request,response);
                 OR
RequestDispatcher dispatcher =servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
dispatcher.foward(request,response);
```

Both gives the same result.

Check this blog for detailed understanding of the RequestDispatcher .
http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/sendredirect-forward-jsp-servlet.html

Comment: that might be `include`

Comment: When you use forward the control is transferred to the next servlet you are calling, while include retains the control with the current servlet, it just includes the processing done by the calling servlet

Comment: Previouslly you called , forward in both line , thats where i have written it